# Merge/Update JSON file with an Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json

I have a source.json file, and then another file of changes which I parse, and need to write out the array back to the source file.  Here is the source.json structure:

```
{
    "users" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "Albin Jaye"
      }
    ],
    "playlists" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "owner_id" : "2",
        "song_ids" : [
          "8",
          "32"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "songs": [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "artist": "Camila Cabello",
        "title": "Never Be the Same"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here is the changes.json structure. I have a CRUD like "add" directive and the "payload" which is the entry to be added to the source file:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "action": "add",
        "payload": [{
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Albin Jaye"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Dave Mustaine"
            }
        ]
    }],
    "playlist": [{
        "action": "add",
        "payload": [{
            "id": "1",
            "owner_id": "2",
            "song_ids": [
                "8",
                "32"
            ]
        }]
    }],
    "songs": [{
        "action": "add",
        "payload": [{
            "id": "1",
            "artist": "Camila Cabello",
            "title": "Never Be the Same"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I have written this code in Node to read in the source file and parse and then read in the changes file. Once the changes file is read, I iterate over and see what "CRUD" directive is there. When I find "add", I then push the payload to an array.  After I get finished, when I console log out I get this:

```
[
  [ 'users', '[object Object],[object Object]' ],
  [ 'playlists', '[object Object]' ],
  [ 'songs', '[object Object]' ]
]
```

This is swell. BUT, I need now to take this result and Stringify it I think and place it back into the source JSON file in the appropriate place. I think it will be some type of ```fs.appendFile()`` function, but not sure.  Here is my code so far:

```
// Stream in source file
    fs.readFile('./' + inputFile, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let input = JSON.parse(data);
        //console.log(input);
    });

    // Stream in changes file
    fs.readFile('./' + changesFile, 'utf-8', (err, jsonString) => {
    if (err)  {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            try {
                const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
            
                const array = [];

                Object.entries(data).map(([key, [{ action,  payload }]]) => {
                    switch (key) {
                        case 'users': {
                            if (action === 'add') {
                                console.log("it's an add");
                                array.push([`${key}`, `${payload}`]);
                            }
                        break;
                        }

                     case 'playlists': {
                        if (action === 'add') {
                            console.log("it's an add");
                            array.push([`${key}`, `${payload}`]);
                        }
                            break;
                        }
                    
                        case 'songs': {
                        if (action === 'add') {
                            console.log("it's an add");
                            array.push([`${key}`, `${payload}`]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                 }
                });
                
                console.log(array);

            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Error parsing JSON', err);
            }
        }
    }); 

    // after we have merged changes and source we need to write out
    // Don't know how to merge the changes array I created above back into the 
    // source.json file?
    fs.appendFile('./' + outputFile, JSON.stringify(array, null, 2), err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('File sucessfully written');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why are you storing the changes in an array instead of mutating the original data object? If you mutate the original data object, you can then write the changes using `fs.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(data))`.

Comment: I know. It's a noob implementation for sure. How would you mutate the original data object instead of using an array in the switch?  Totally understand if you don't have time to provide example...or if you could point me where to learn about this.  I knew that there should be a way to easily mutate it without going transferring to arrays and back out...but the fileAppend() seems to only just do that...append to a file....not do the mutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure where you're going with your implementation, but I think a better way to go about this would be to update the original data object with the changes, and then write the changes out to a file:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(inputFile));
const changes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(changesFile));

for(const [table, actions] of Object.entries(changes)){
    if(!(table in data))continue;
    for(const actionDetail of actions){
        if(actionDetail.action === 'add'){
            data[table].push(...actionDetail.payload);
        }
    }
}
fs.writeFileSync(inputFile, JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Exactly!  This is much, much more elegant than me noobing around with going back and forth with arrays and trying to process.  Thanks so much! Helps out a lot.